# Google Home App does not show fan speed and temperature settings for AC unit

Tags: google-smart-home

I'm trying to add an AC Unit to Google Home via Google Smart Actions. I have the action configured and successfully linked my app server to the Google Home App.

I have been using the following guide from Google to develop my app server:

- https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/guides/acunit

In response to Google's `action.devices.SYNC` request I am providing the following response:

```
{
    "requestId": "request-id-providing-by-google",
    "payload": {
        "agentUserId": "unique-user-id",
        "devices": [
            {
                "id": "device-id",
                "type": "action.devices.types.AC_UNIT",
                "traits": [
                    "action.devices.traits.FanSpeed",
                    "action.devices.traits.OnOff",
                    "action.devices.traits.TemperatureSetting"
                ],
                "name": {
                    "name": "Air Conditioner"
                },
                "willReportState": false,
                "roomHint": "Room 1",
                "deviceInfo": {
                    "manufacturer": "man",
                    "model": "hs1234",
                    "hwVersion": "3.2",
                    "swVersion": "11.4"
                },
                "attributes": {
                    "availableFanSpeeds": {
                        "speeds": [
                            {
                                "speed_name": "speed_one",
                                "speed_values": [
                                    {
                                        "speed_synonym": [
                                            "one"
                                        ],
                                        "lang": "en"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "speed_name": "speed_two",
                                "speed_values": [
                                    {
                                        "speed_synonym": [
                                            "two"
                                        ],
                                        "lang": "en"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "speed_name": "speed_three",
                                "speed_values": [
                                    {
                                        "speed_synonym": [
                                            "three"
                                        ],
                                        "lang": "en"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "speed_name": "speed_four",
                                "speed_values": [
                                    {
                                        "speed_synonym": [
                                            "four"
                                        ],
                                        "lang": "en"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "speed_name": "speed_five",
                                "speed_values": [
                                    {
                                        "speed_synonym": [
                                            "five"
                                        ],
                                        "lang": "en"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "ordered": true
                    },
                    "supportsFanSpeedPercent": false,
                    "availableThermostatModes": [
                        "off",
                        "heat",
                        "cool",
                        "fan-only",
                        "dry",
                        "on"
                    ],
                    "thermostatTemperatureRange": {
                        "minThresholdCelsius": 18,
                        "maxThresholdCelsius": 30
                    },
                    "thermostatTemperatureUnit": "C"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And in response to Google's `action.devices.QUERY` request I am providing this response:

```
{
    "requestId": "request-id-providing-by-google",
    "payload": {
        "devices": {
            "device-id": {
                "status": "SUCCESS",
                "online": true,
                "on": true,
                "currentFanSpeedSetting": "speed-five",
                "thermostatMode": "off",
                "thermostatTemperatureAmbient": 25,
                "thermostatTemperatureSetpoint": 20,
                "thermostatHumidityAmbient": 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have:

- Specified that my AC unit supports the On / Off, fan speeds and temperature setting traits
- Given the necessary attributes for the specified traits
- Provided the current values for the device and related traits

However, when I view this device in the Google Home App it only presents an On / Off button and no controls for fan speed and temperature.

I have looked through all related logs on Google Cloud Logging and there are no errors reports.

I have reviewed these seemingly related issues on the topic but the responses and comments have not resolved the issue:

- https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs/issues/500
- https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs/issues/330

Am I missing some parameters or config for these controls to appear?

**Update 07/11 -** [Useful response from @ToniCorinne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69744071/5853274) pointing out that on the Google Home Smartphone app FanSpeed controls are not currently supported, see this link:

- https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/touch-controls#google_home_app

Obviously this doesn't account for TemperatureSettings, so I've opened the following bug with Google which at time of writing has not been assigned:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/205157683

Answer (score 1):

`FanSpeed` is not currently a supported trait with [touch controls in the Google Home app](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/touch-controls#google_home_app).

`TemperatureSetting` for an `AC_Unit` should have touch-controls, however. You could file an issue on the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148) with your SYNC response and applicable information like the Google Home app version you're seeing this issue on for more help.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes you're right it looks as though FanSpeed is not listed as a supported trait for the Google Home app, but TemperatureSetting is. I am getting neither, though am able to control both traits by voice command, which tells me that I have it set up correctly.

Comment: I currently have the same problem. AC is added in SmartThings which is synced with Google home. I can only turn on or off with touch and set mode. No temp controls. I can control the temp via voice assistant though